# C# Setting specific ident settings to XmlWriterSettings

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am coding an C# easy tool to perform some attribute changes to a given XML file.
All the coding envolved to perform the changes are working as expected however when it comes to save the file I have the following issue,
source XML file has a specific ident such as:

```
<AAL2Bearer id="0" method="create">
<attributes>
<pathId>16</pathId>
<vccId>VCC/2</vccId></attributes></AAL2Bearer>
<AAL2Bearer id="1" method="create">
<attributes>
<pathId>8</pathId>
<vccId>VCC/3</vccId></attributes></AAL2Bearer>
<AAL2Bearer id="2" method="create">
<attributes>
<pathId>1</pathId>
<vccId>VCC/5</vccId></attributes></AAL2Bearer>
```

My XML File after saving it:

```
<AAL2Bearer id="0" method="create">
<attributes>
<pathId>16</pathId>
<vccId>VCC/2</vccId>
</attributes>
</AAL2Bearer>
<AAL2Bearer id="1" method="create">
<attributes>
<pathId>8</pathId>
<vccId>VCC/3</vccId>
</attributes>
</AAL2Bearer>
<AAL2Bearer id="2" method="create">
<attributes>
<pathId>1</pathId>
<vccId>VCC/5</vccId>
</attributes>
</AAL2Bearer>
```

I have tried:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = "";
```

With this snippet I am able to have a XML file with no ident in the begining of each line, which is what I need however I also need to close the xml node in the same line, basically only add new line on new xml node but always "close" the XML node and its parents in the same line.

Thanks and regards

Comment: A parser wont care about the lines upon which the nodes are closed, why does it matter?

Comment: It does matter as to where I am uploading the modified xml would reject the file as invalied if this type of ident isn't applied.

Comment: You are correct Alex K. it was the BOM. Sorry for my mistake! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the question and Alex K. was right!

File was being marked as invalid due to the BOM. :(

Simply solve by:

```
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "";
        var outputEnc = new UTF8Encoding(false);
        settings.Encoding = outputEnc;
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(targetXWO.FileName, settings))
        {
             doc.Save(writer);
        }
```

Thanks